# How to make an instance variables inside a class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows

I'm learning the Windows Application Form in Visual Studio, I'm making a number guessing game where the program generates a random number.
I put the random number generator inside the Button_Click method, I want the number to say the same when the program start but it change every time I click the button.

```
public partial class myWindow : Form
{


    public myWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void guessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Random random = new Random();
            int roll = random.Next(0, 99);
```

Where should I declare or put the random number generator and variable so it doesn't change ?

Comment: Try `Random random = new Random(1);`

Comment: @YacoubMassad Good for a guessing game you can run one time. :)

Comment: Should the second button click always show the same number? And the third...?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "I want the number to say the same when the program start but it change every time I click the button"?

Comment: @YacoubMassad - I think he wants the program to generate a random number when the game starts, but to only generate a new one **after** the user has successfully guessed the current number - not every time the user guesses.

Comment: One small note - be careful with `random.Next(0, 99)` as this generates a number from `0 .. 98`. The `99` is an **exclusive** upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a class member:

```
public partial class myWindow : Form
{
    private int _roll;
    private int _numGuesses;

    public Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random random = new Random();
        _roll = random.Next(0, 99);
    }

    private void guessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isGuessCorrect = // Set this however you need to

        if (isGuessCorrect)
        {
            // They got it right!
        }
        else
        {
            _numGuesses++;
            if (_numGuesses > 9)
            {
                // Tell them they failed
            }
            else
            {
                // Tell them they're wrong, but have 10 - _numGuesses guesses left
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope I don't bother you much, but i want the player to have 10 chances to guess the right number.
I know i have to put a for loop, but again i don't know what to put the loop.

Comment: You'll need to track the number of guess also. I'll update my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for your help I really appreciate it.